# How can I activate multiple buttons in one slide gesture with SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have 25 buttons laid out in a grid for a game like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqKVU.png).

I'm generating these buttons like this:

```
VStack {
  ForEach(1..<6) {_ in
    HStack {
      ForEach(1..<6) {_ in
        Button(action: {
          // Button clicked
          doButton()
        }) {
          Rectangle()
            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
            .border(Color.black, lineWidth: 1)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I make it so if the user drags their finger across multiple buttons, each one of the buttons are clicked, and doButton() is executed?

I tried using a DragGesture() but couldn't get it to work...

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5.1, iOS 13.

I don't have a 100% solution for you, but I do have something to get you off the ground hopefully. These are not buttons, but simply squares. As I click/drag across them they^ll signal I passed by.

It isn't perfect, but should give you some thing more to work with.
I read a tutorial on medium on doing something similar with drag and drop. [This one](https://medium.com/better-programming/build-a-board-game-without-the-politics-part-1-3f17f29eeb0b).

Can help but think you'll need to do something with drag here and the Geometry reader ultimately, detecting where they are and responding to that.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
 return VStack {
  ForEach(1..<6) {colY in
    HStack {
      ForEach(1..<6) {rowX in
          boxView(row: rowX, col: colY)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
}

struct boxView: View {
 @State var row: Int
 @State var col: Int
 var body: some View {
 let dragGesture = DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: CoordinateSpace.global)
  .onChanged { (value) in
    print("trigger ",self.row,self.col)
  }
 return Rectangle()
    .stroke(Color.black)
    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
    .gesture(dragGesture)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import SwiftUI

class Container : ObservableObject {
    @Published var location = CGPoint()
    public func updateLocation(_ location: CGPoint) {
        self.location = location
    }
}

struct SliderGestureButtonsView: View {
    @ObservedObject var container = Container()
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(1..<6) { colY in
                HStack {
                    ForEach(1..<6) { rowX in
                        GeometryReader { gp in
                            let x = gp.frame(in:.named("hive")).midX
                            let y = gp.frame(in:.named("hive")).midY
                            let w = gp.frame(in:.named("hive")).size.width
                            let h = gp.frame(in:.named("hive")).size.height
                            let rect = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: w, height: h)
                            boxView(row: rowX, col: colY, rect: rect, container: container)
                        }
                    }
                }.frame(height: 60)
            }
        }.coordinateSpace(name: "hive").frame(width: 300)
        .gesture(
            DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: CoordinateSpace.named("hive"))
            .onChanged { (value) in
                container.updateLocation(value.location)
            }
        )
    }
}


struct boxView: View {
    var row: Int
    var col: Int
    var rect: CGRect
    @ObservedObject var container: Container
    var body: some View {
        let x = container.location.x
        let y = container.location.y
        
        let hw = rect.size.width / 2
        let ox = rect.origin.x
        let withinX = x > ox - hw && x < ox + hw
        
        let hh = rect.size.height / 2
        let oy = rect.origin.y
        let withinY = y > oy - hh && y < oy + hh
        
        var pressed = false

        if(withinX && withinY) {
            pressed = true
            print("trigger ", self.row, self.col)
        }

        return Rectangle()
                .stroke(Color.white)
                .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                .background(pressed ? Color.green : Color.black)
    }
}
```